# crontab - Nothing happens

Tags: linux, cron

I'm new to crontab and I thought I understood how it works, but apparently not.
What am I doing wrong ?

I have added a few line in cron using :

```
    crontab -e
```

I believe the following line should do this :

1. run every 1/4 houres rsnapshot hourly
2. run at 3:30 every day rsnapshot daily
3. run at 3:00 once in a week (monday) rsnapshot weekly
4. run at 2:30 once in a month (the 1st of each month) rsnapshot monthly

   ```
   0 */15  * * *           /usr/bin/rsnapshot hourly
   30 3    * * *           /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
   0  3    * * 1           /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly
   30 2    1 * *           /usr/bin/rsnapshot monthly
   ```

I have been waiting about 2 houres now, and rsnapshot hourly didn't happened.

Can someone explain me what I missed ?

Comment: I marked this as duplicate as there are quite a lot of "My cronjob is not running"-related questions, the linked one being merely an example. I suggest you also take a look at [the info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) of the `cron`-tag, it provides some info on how to best debug these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 0):

The crontab looks ok, however there a number of reason that it may not have run.

You should check the following:

- check the system log to see if it attempted to run and failed;
- verify your user has permissions to run /usr/bin/rsnapshot;
- verify that your system doesn't have a cron.allow file, or if it does, you are in it;
- verify your system doesn't have a cron.deny file with you in it;
- verify cron is actually running.

Comment: I have just edited */15 to 15 and it seems to be working ! It's not doing exactly what I excepted him to do, but it will do for now. I'll look for a real fix as soon as possible.